# Implementation of the Google Identity Toolkit (openid like)

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I´m trying to weite a module that implements the folliwing google api
http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/index.html

it´s kind of like the openid, uses external accounts from the api to allow users to login without having to register the anoying long register form and pass through all verification

I´m new to D7 and openid conpcepts, what i´ve tested was the openid module that comes with D7 and got very disapointed...

first of all I had to have an openid url then I had to create the user and aprove my validation link from my email in order to get logged in to my drupal

that´s useless... because I went through basicaly the same process

What I want is something similar as this StackExchange experience, I used my gmail account and got logged in, I only had to login to google and that was it...

Any ideeas from where to begin with the implementation ?
I want to be able to sync automaticaly the users that will use the Google Id kit with Drupal, without asking too many questions.. because after all what I´m interested is them be able to leave a trail on my site but do encourage them to register easily...

update:

found on google documentation this page
http://code.google.com/apis/identitytoolkit/v1/drupalsample.html

Comment: I suggest you add that as an answer and accept it to mark the question as closed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement it in specific open source platform, please use Google Identity Toolkit Plugins. There is a plugin for opencart 1.4.x: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3302

It only asks you for 3 installation steps without any coding work to make your dream become true! =)

Drupal plugin for it will be alive soon.

Comment: I've actually made the plugin..don't know how can I make it available for the whole drupal comunity...